# Unable to display object alias as object header inside a frame or package

Tags: alias, graphviz, diagram, dot, plantuml

Using plantuml I would like to create an object with an alias, so I can manipulate the object by means of it's actual name/ID (`bar` and `baz` in my example), but its header will show the alias ("Foo"). Also, I would like to group objects in some frame or package.

Here's my sample [code](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/TOz1hi8m34JtFeL_jlyINN4F9qtRq2IE79TM8EwEGOW54jxDlAUHF7GbqQrae9nvB-b8TOQ-fjf8gA2diCx2Mnq3PnPKeTeDnQhmfqii4I_92rc4ISYYsrdMoROStW0GcotGRBqd3Oj3wjYCe1txSmoAdiJY7U3Jk1FpopJqTl_n-2rTloJJXbZ7vriF).

```
@startuml
allowmixing
skinparam backgroundcolor transparent
!theme vibrant

frame "workflow" {

  package "batch" as p {
    object bar
  }

  object "Foo" as bar {
    + x
  }

  object "Foo" as baz {
    + x
  }
}
@enduml
```

And this is the result:

[image]

You can see how the object that is outside the package has the expected "Foo" alias as header (instead of its name/ID `baz`), whereas the other object inside the "batch" package shows its `bar` name/ID in the header instead of the expected "Foo" alias.

How can I achieve a "Foo" header for the `bar` object also? Thanks.

I'm using the following configuration:

- Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
- PlantUML version 1.2022.14 (Tue Dec 06 19:24:13 CET 2022)
  (GPL source distribution)
- Java Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
- Default Encoding: UTF-8
- Language: en
- Country: GB
- PLANTUML_LIMIT_SIZE: 4096
- Dot version: dot - graphviz version 7.1.0 (0)
- Installation seems OK. File generation OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are used on associations, I think.

If I define the object inside the package, I get this:

```
@startuml
allowmixing
skinparam backgroundcolor transparent
!theme vibrant

frame "workflow" {

  package "batch" as p {
    object "Foo" as bar {
      + x
    }
  }

  object "Foo" as baz {
    + x
  }
}
@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, defining the objects directly inside packages does the trick. Thanks a lot!